# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el formato de la fecha en una columna?

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I have LibreOffice 7.3.7.2 installed. To change the format of a text column (mm/dd/yyyy), I follow the steps below:

```
I select the column
Format/Date /12/31/1999
I select the column
Data/Text to columns/Default/(AMD).
```

The format doesn’t change.

Mi problema es el siguiente. Trabajo con un Office que viene por defecto en Linuxmint. De un banco español descargo archivos csv con cotizaciones. En los archivos hay una columna con fechas (ejemplo 15/12/2008) y otra con precios, ambas con formato 'número/General'. Para importar con un script de Python, quiero convertir los datos en la columna con fechas al formato '2008/12/15. Intento hacer esta operación de la forma que he descrito, sin éxito, en la pregunta.

What am I doing wrong?. I will appreciate help.

Answer (score 0):

La solución ha sido la sugerida por [Villeroy](https://ask.libreoffice.org/u/Villeroy) in the [link](https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/data-text-to-columns-default-amd-dont-running/86562/18)